# How to run only selected jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have some jobs in diffrent folders. Jobs are trigered sequenced using post-build actions. I looking for plugin to run only selected(in easy way, checkbox or something) jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@crash thanks for the hint.

I used code from https://youarewhatyoucode.com/2017/08/04/find-jobs-in-all-jenkins-folders/ to list all jobs in folder. Then creates a list of checkboxes, and run jobs if it is selected.

```
def list = []
findAll("tests/.*").each{
    job ->
    list.add(booleanParam(name: "$job.fullName", defaultValue: false, description: 'dynamic')) 
}


properties([parameters(list)])

node{
    stage('test'){
        params.each{
            p ->
            if(p.getValue() == true)
            {
                echo p.getKey()
                build p.getKey()
            }   
        }


    }
}

def isFolder(abstractJob){
 return abstractJob.getClass().getName() == "com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder"
}

def collectJobRecursively(abstractJob,resultCollector){
  if(isFolder(abstractJob))
        {
            abstractJob.items.findAll().each{ nestedJob ->
            collectJobRecursively(nestedJob,resultCollector)
        }
  }
  else
  {
    //only add actual jobs to the list
    resultCollector << abstractJob
  }
}

def findAll(pattern = '.*'){
 def resultCollector = []
 Jenkins.instance.items.findAll().each{ job ->
    collectJobRecursively(job,resultCollector)
  }

  return resultCollector
  .findAll{
    // apply the regular expression here.
    // we are matching the Full Name (including folder names)
      (it.fullName =~ /$pattern/)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to [define a choice parameter](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-parameters)s and then use the `when {}` declaration to check for the parameters value?

For example:

```
when {
    expression {
        return params.MY_CHOICE == 'myfirstchoice'
    }
}
```

If you need a multi-select choice parameters then take a look at the [Extended Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/) plugin.